# Change precision for many int values with text in balloon text on data points in amCharts candlestick charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am confused on how to change the precision of high, open, low, close in candlestick chart in amCharts specially when balloon also comprises text.

This is different from other answers I found on Stack Overflow as they are for valueAxes and categoryAxes balloons but not for data point balloons (with text).

For example:

[image]

In this balloon, for eg, if I want to show 3 digits after decimals. Also in some cases I am a facing problem where values are rounded and shown as eg. 12k. But I want real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the built-in short tags (i.e. `[open]` `[high]`, `[value]`, etc), you can set a `precision` inside your [graph object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#precision) or at the [chart level](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#precision) to the desired number of decimals:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  precision: 3, //affects everything
  // ...
  graphs: [{
   // ...
   precision: 3, //affects just this graph 
  },
  // repeat as needed
  ],
  // ...
});
```

Stock charts need this set in the [panel](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#precision) or in [panelsSettings](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PanelsSettings#precision)

If you're accessing your values by name instead of through the built-in tags, you'll need to use the [balloonFunction](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction) to format your data. There's an example in the knowledge base that illustrates this [here](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-balloonfunction-to-format-proprietary-data-in-balloon/).

Comment: You pointed out all different aspects & ways to solve my question. Ideal Answer. Thanks.